# Editing TestAdore scripts by default

Tags: manual-testing

After installing [TestAdore](http://testadore.com/), the tests (TA files) are automatically executed when double clicked in Explorer.

This is typically ok, but right now I'm in the test definition phase, so I'd like to edit them by default instead of running them.

Is there a way to edit them by default?

Comment: It looks like @Thomas Weller owns TestAdore?

Comment: @Dan: yes. I was asked this question via support a few times and I wanted to make it findable by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by changing the file associations in the Registry, e.g. to Notepad++

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ta]
@="TestAdoreTest"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestAdoreTest]
@="TestAdore Test Case"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestAdoreTest\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestAdoreTest\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestAdoreTest\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

I found it convenient to have another entry in the context menu to be able to run them:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestAdoreTest\shell\exec]
@="Run with TestAdore Performer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TestAdoreTest\shell\exec\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WelliSolutions\\TestAdore\\PerformerXml.exe\" \"%1\""
```